# How to find PID's user name in Linux?

Tags: linux, pid

Can you help me to find the PID's user name?

Sometimes my server has high load. When I run `top -c`, I cannot even find the owner of a process which is causing load on the server.

Comment: We were experiencing server load issue due to bulk php process, so that i had this question, we can then find them using 'lsof -p xxxx'.

Answer (score 58):

I'm surprised nobody has put this up yet:

Try the `-p` option of the [`ps`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) command.

For instance, if you have PID `1234`, run:

```
ps -u -p 1234
```

The `-u` was added to include the username in the output.

You can then use `grep` or `awk`, etc. to extract the info you want.

Comment: You were a tick faster than me. You're waking up earlier? Depending on the Linux distrbution, `ps u 1234` (Debian) or just `ps 1234` (Android with Busybox) also works.

Comment: This works nicely with [`pgrep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) when you only have the process name (not the PID) or when you want to see the owners of multiple processes with a similar name: `ps -u -p $(pgrep yourProcessName)`

Answer (score 9):

`/proc/processID/status` will have the information about user's ID which you can use to find the username.

This does the same:

```
uid=$(awk '/^Uid:/{print $2}' /proc/YOUR_PROCESS_ID/status)
getent passwd "$uid" | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Replace YOUR_PROCESS_ID with your process ID number.

Comment: The best answer, since it's the fastest, especially if changed to : `getent passwd $(< /proc/"$uid"/loginuid) | sed 's/\:.*$//'`

Comment: This is the best answer if you are looking for fullname.

Answer (score 7):

Get only username from a PID:

```
PID=136323
USERNAME="$( ps -o uname= -p "${PID}" )"
```

You can also combine it with a `pgrep`. In this example we show all usernames executing some `.php` file:

```
pgrep -f '\.php' | xargs -r ps -o uname= -p | sort -u
```

Find only one username running a certain unique process:

```
USERNAME="$( pgrep -nf 'script\.php' | xargs -r ps -o uname= -p )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the shortest way is:

```
id -nu </proc/<pid>/loginuid
```

The `/proc/<pid>/loginuid` file has the uid number of the user running the process; `id -nu` reads uid from stdin and returns a user name.

Comment: Nice. Is there a file of uid to user names that you can map the loginuid to a string user name?

Comment: Good answer, one of the best, but needs correction a bit. This _will_ work (bash example): `id -nu $(< /proc/<pid>/loginuid)` (to work with any POSIX shell sholud be escaped with backticks instead of "$( )" bash construction). The answer with `ps` is more flexible, you can get also _real_ and _saved_ user name. But this answer command is several times faster than `ps --no-headers -o euser -p <pid>`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly? On my system, if I run 'top -c' I get:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S   %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                        
  2873 matt      20   0 3022m 1.6g 1.6g S     22 21.6   2245:42 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --comment ESX5-1 --startvm 4fd78ee9-739a-4d53-a0ce-4f9819ab9411 --no-startvm-errormsgbox        
  29764matt      20   0 2779m 1.4g 1.3g S      5 18.4 210:33.51 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --comment win2008-2 --startvm 202ec2b7-ae12-40e9-af76-2be429e553d7 --no-startvm-errormsgbox     
  17281root      20   0     0    0    0 S      2  0.0   0:05.90 [kworker/u:2]
```

So the PID (processus/task identifier) is the first column, and the user account the processus runs under is the second column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command.

```
use ps aux| grep "pid"
```

Also,

```
ls -ld /proc/"pid"/exe
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).